# Snowflake While loop to continue sql until @Counter reaches 365

Tags: sql, while-loop, counter, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to make my code stop counting when it reaches a certain number, but I keep getting an error that I cannot have a select statement after the Declare.

```
DECLARE @Counter INT 
SET @Counter=1
WHILE ( @Counter <= 365)
BEGIN
    
select Geography
, concat('Latest_Week_End ',current_date - @Counter) as WE_DATE
,concat(Department_ID,' ',Department_NM)
,Group_NM
,concat(category_ID,' ',category_nm)
,Sum(Dollar_sales)
,Sum(dollar_Sales_ya)
,Sum(unit_sales)
,sum(unit_sales_ya)
,sum(rom_dollars)
,sum(rom_dollars_ya)
,sum(rom_units)
,sum(rom_units_ya) from TEMP_TABLES.MR_OMNIDASH_IRI_SHARE
where geography like '%PORTLAND%'
and WE_Date in (current_date - @Counter)
group by 1,2,3,4,5
SET @Counter  = @Counter  + 7
END
```

Comment: It looks like you're using T-SQL with snowflake. Snowflake doc here https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/session-variables.html says you use `SET` not `DECLARE`

Comment: I changed it to Set and took out "BEGIN" and put {} around the query, but I'm getting an error that says there is an unexpected "WHILE". Any idea if I'm using the wrong format or something? Thank you!

Comment: If you're looking for a WHILE loop in standard SQL, then Snowflake doesn't currently support that type of scripting (coming soon).  Until then, you'll need to wrap that into a JavaScript UDTF or modify the SQL to not use a loop at all.  It doesn't seem like the logic would be difficult to create with a single SQL statement rather than a loop.

Comment: Instead of using a `WHILE` loop you should join to an existing calendar table. That is a completely standard analytics pattern. But you have to actually learn snowflake language, you can't just use a different language and expect it to work. Here is more details on a calendar table in snowflake (I just googled it) https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z00008MprP2SAJ/snowflake-how-to-build-a-calendar-dim-table

Answer (score 1):

Could you try a different approach ?

```
select  current_date() - seq4()*7 from table(generator(rowcount => 52))
```

Returns the last 52 week end dates for the last year.

[image]

Your line:

```
and WE_Date in (current_date - @Counter)
```

Could be replaced with

```
and WE_Date in (select  current_date() - seq4()*7 from table(generator(rowcount => 52)))
```

And all should be good?